# Null reference object in linq data class

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, linq

I have created a table in mysql "Customers", and  I have created a devart linq connect model.

When I want to retrieve the first row using `linq` it gives a `null reference exception`

> (*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*)

My code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ShoppingDataContext data = new ShoppingDataContext())
    {              
        Customer Mycustomer = data.Customers.First();
        Labelshow.Text = Mycustomer.CustomerLastname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown in the code? On the "using" line, or on the call to First(), or in the label assignment?

Comment: DO you just saw if the variable data have values?

Comment: @DavidW exception is thrown at Labelshow.Text = mycustomer.CustomerLastname

Comment: @MayogaX : it has values i have seen it in debug mode now..

Comment: @VishalTorne Are you saying Mycustomer is, itself, not null, or that CustomerLastname has a value?

Comment: @DavidW it is containing the lastname which i need , when i hover my mouse over to CustomerLastname but it is not displaying in the label. i don't know what's happening. myCustomer is not null

Comment: Perhaps you should post at least a portion of the HTML (aspx) markup. Best I can infer from what you've described is there's some problem in the declaration of your label control (Labelshow), if Mycustomer.CustomerLastname contains a valid string value.

Comment: apsx label: <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="maincontent" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Label ID="Labelshow" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Comment: @DavidW sorry i have done an terrible mistake.. i just slipped out of the master page into the content of other page .. appreciate your help..thanks